# Use '%' with column names in MYSQL select statement?

Tags: mysql

I have a query that looks at partial matches within two mysql tables to make a join:

```
SELECT table1.column, table2.column FROM table1, table2 WHERE table1.val LIKE table2.val
```

This works fine as a join, but... some of the values in table2 are actually substrings of the values in table one—specifically they're urls. So, table1.val might equal http://google.com while table2.val = google.com.

How do I use the '%' operator around the table2 val to make this comparison.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this:

```
... WHERE table1.val LIKE CONCAT('%', table2.val, '%')
```

Note that this will not perform as well as `table1.val = table2.val`, as it must now search all rows in `table2`.

Answer (score 0):

> Q: How do I use the '%' operator around the table2 val to make this
>   comparison.

A: You don't :)

You can specify a column by name (e.g. "mycolumn"), by fully qualified name (e.g. "mytable.myname") or by ordinal (e.g. "1").